# WSL2 ubuntu 20.04 tamil font headless

Tags: fonts, windows-subsystem-for-linux, headless

I am on trials to use `trans` to translate one language to the other on WSL2 ubuntu 20.04.

Basically, I am trying to reproduce [this](https://ostechnix.com/use-google-translate-commandline-linux/)

I have done these so far:

- Administrator: Windows PowerShell
- git clone https://github.com/powerline/fonts.git
- cd fonts
- set-executionpolicy bypass
- .\install.ps1
- Set-ExecutionPolicy Default
- Selected new font as the  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REKso.png)  depicts.
- Also, I noticed that, in WSL Ubuntu-20.04 the  [fonts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOKvs.png)  are already installed.

I still see the dumb characters when I copy paste `trans வணக்கம்`

I am wondering how `putty` over `ssh` is able to  [render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaJTs.png)  on copy paste but fails to reproduce in the output of the command.

Any guidance is appreciated.

**EDIT**
I installed 'fonts-powerline package `sudo apt-get install fonts-powerline` and this also did NOT work ...

I installed relevant font packages as in here[trial3](https://sudhakaryblog.wordpress.com/2020/01/11/conemu-wsl-telugu/) (for tamil).

Tried hack as in here [trial2](https://x410.dev/cookbook/wsl/sharing-windows-fonts-with-wsl/)

**Issue persists.**

Comment: I don't know for sure if this will fix it, but I would recommend trying Windows Terminal, which is Microsoft's replacement for the more than 20-year old legacy Console.  You can install it from the Microsoft Store.  It's also open-source.  They have put a lot of work into font and character handling, so maybe it will react better.  Windows Terminal will automatically detect and create a profile for WSL/Ubuntu when you launch it.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I installed it from Microsoft store and confirm that it did NOT work for now. Thank you.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds, The good news is I issued command `wsl` at the "windows terminal" prompt resulting in BASH prompt and at this new BASH prompt, it rendered the tamil, telugu, hindi fonts. I also confirm that there are editing issues in thus formed new prompt inside "windows terminal". The standard issue (NOT rendering inside ubuntu window) remains ...